# Ошибка при выполнении кода 'NoneType' object is not subscriptable

Tags: python, csv

```
import requests
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import csv
from datetime import datetime

def get_html(url):
    r = requests.get(url) #Response
    return r.text         #Возвращает html код страницы


def get_url_links(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html,'lxml')

    links = []

    for names in soup.find_all('div',class_='cmc-table__column-name sc-1kxikfi-0 eTVhdN'):
        name = names.find('a').get('href')
        link = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/' + name
        links.append(link)

    return links

def get_page_data(html):
    soup = BeautifulSoup(html, 'lxml')

    try:
        nameg = soup.find('h1').text.strip()
    except:
        nameg=''

    try:
        price = soup.find('span', id='cmc-details-panel-price__price').text.strip()
    except:
        price=''

    data = {'nameg':nameg,
            'price':price}

def write_csv(data):
    with open('coinmarketapp.csv','a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow((data['name'],data['price']))

        print(data['name'], 'parsed')

data = {'name': 'answer', 'price': 42}
write_csv(data)

wrong_data = None
# write_csv(wrong_data)



def main():
    start = datetime.now()

    url = 'https://coinmarketcap.com/'
    all_links = get_url_links(get_html(url))

    for url in all_links:
        html = get_html(url)
        data = get_page_data(html)
        write_csv(data)

    end = datetime.now()

    total = end - start
    print(str(total))


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: У вас в data['name'] или data['price'] есть None.

Comment: Да, что у вас в `data`?

Comment: У вас сама ```data``` является пустым объектом

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Функция рабочая, надо только вызывать с правильными данными:

```
import csv

def write_csv(data):
    with open('coinmarketapp.csv','a') as f:
        writer = csv.writer(f)

        writer.writerow((data['name'],data['price']))

        print(data['name'], 'parsed')

data = {'name': 'answer', 'price': 42}
write_csv(data)

wrong_data = None
write_csv(wrong_data)
```

Comment: Благодарю,но по прежнему выскакивает та же ошибка

Comment: @Varikk в моём коде закомментируйте последнюю строку, если вы об ошибке в моём коде

Comment: Закомментировал,все равно та же ошибка) Странно.

Comment: @Varikk https://repl.it/repls/VacantRemorsefulApplicationserver никаких ошибок

Comment: Странно,копирую тот же код,все равно вылазит ошибка. Бред какой-то

Comment: @Varikk куда вы копируете? К себе в проект? Сделайте отдельный тестовый скрипт, который содержит только мой код и проверьте

Comment: Интересно конечно... Никаких ошибок нет,почему тогда у меня в проекте это не работает? И огромная вам кстати благодарность за помощь

Comment: @Varikk ну => что у вас где-то в другом месте проблема, которое не приведено в вопросе :) Покажите больше кода проекта, чтобы было понятно. Например, `data` на пути к вызову функции может где-то меняться, превращаясь в `None`. Поставьте диагностический вывод прямо возле вызова функции, чтобы удостовериться что нормальная `data` передаётся

Comment: Тогда сейчас создам новый вопрос с полным кодом

Comment: Готово,скопировалось конечно криво,но надеюсь вы поняли суть

Comment: @Varikk Чтобы нормально отображалось надо выбрать весь код и нажать выше в заголовке окна { } ("пример кода") тогда нормально всё будет. Я поправил.

Comment: @Varikk `get_page_data(html)` возвращает `None`

Comment: Благодарю вас,буду знать,так что можно сделать что-бы решить проблему?

Comment: Хмм... действительно

Comment: @Varikk написать `return data` в конце функции `get_page_data`

Comment: @Varikk и для будущего вопроса - заменить `nameg` на `name`

Comment: Фууух,наконец-то. Благодарю вас. Тут можно лайк или что то типо этого поставить?)))

Comment: @Varikk примите ответ с помощью галки слева от него под голосами

Comment: Сделал,еще раз огромное вам спасибо